# Facebook LoginButton does not work in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, facebook

I am struggling with an odd behaviour here. I have a DialogFragment and in there in have a LoginButton. When clicking it, obviously, I expect the user to Login Facebook.

The code I have is working perfectly fine in a only-one activity project. When I brought the code to my real project, simply the Facebook's login dialog won't show up.

I have found the following URL http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OMGyXIBlu34J:developers.facebridge.net/bugs/248010695326479%3Fbrowse%3Dsearch_519371e4319283b59535107+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

This guy reports a possible problem with Facebook's code and, in fact I have debugged the code and it's a ContextWrapper. So I added his code, but still does not work.

My code is fairly simple:

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(mActivity, callback);
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));

.....

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

.....


private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
            new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.i(TAG, state.name());
            if(session.isOpened())
                IS_SOCIAL = true;
        }
    };
```

That's pretty much it... I get "OPENING" state, but nothing else. It stops there.

Anyone seen this?

Regards,
Felipe

**EDIT 1**
Found what the problem was:
My Activity's `onActivityResult` was being invoked. I am not sure why. So what I did was:

```
if(requestCode == 64206) //Bad hacking
//df is the DialogFragment
            if(df!=null) {
                df.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
```

That made it work... I wonder if there's a cleaner solution?

Comment: To avoid using 64206, you can use
`if(requestCode == Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE)`
which equals 0xface (hex value for 64206)

Answer (score 4):

You should add

```
loginButton.setFragment(this);
```

to your Fragment. This will cause the onActivityResult in your fragment to be called rather than the containing activity.

Comment: I am not using the Android Support library, so unfortunately I cannot do this.

Comment: But they're equivalent, why wouldn't you use the support library for fragments (it allows your app to go on more devices as well). The only thing that needs to change is your imports.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I am forcing the new generation of Android 4+ phones. I don't want to support the old ones :)

Comment: And you can't cast the Fragment from Support Library Base Library on 4+

Comment: The SDK needs to support lower levels of Android, which is why we chose to use the support library. In your case, you can either forward the onActivityResult from your Activity class, or you could change the imports to use the Fragment classes from the support library (which should not affect your app at all).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your logcat after you pressed the login button ? There has to be a hint maybe. Does the login view showed ? Did you login and get no token ?

Comment: Hi Luser. I found out what the problem was. Check out my Edit.

Comment: Cool, nice to know these hacks ;)